# Rails custom script/console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, console

In this movie http://media.railscasts.com/videos/181_include_vs_joins.mov you can see he is using a custom ./script/console and all find results are shown nicely like this
[alt text http://www.mandatela.si/console.png](http://www.mandatela.si/console.png)

Is there a plugin for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a nice little gem called [hirb](http://github.com/cldwalker/hirb).

Answer (score 2):

mytaka has it right.  For future reference Ryan Bates, the creator of railscasts, almost always has the required gems listed on the railscast post for each video.  In this case it is listed [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins).  It also has a few tips on using hirb in the comments.

My guess is that you arrived at the video via one of the many aggregators that strip out the context of the videos.  I'm not sure why but several of them seem to have more google juice that the original site.